Using ckeditor5. Is it possible to click on tab key and cursor move to next XXX in text
I am using ckeditor 5 to copy paste text. This text has XXX in it. When tab key is pressed i want cursor to go to next XXX in text. These are standard form text templates.
I tried different SOLUTIONS either cursor does not move or instead of staying inside editor go to url address. It treat editor as whole as one elemnt.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
